# SceneDelegate with Conditional Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode

Prior to Xcode 11, one could conditionally set which Storyboard to start with on an iOS app inside `AppDelegate`. Now with the addition of `SceneDelegate` it is to my understanding that you can instantiate that same logic there, which I am having issues with.

If I set the `Storyboard Name` inside `Application Scene Manifest` I can get the app to always start on the same Storyboard, but I want to conditionally start on one of two Storyboards.

I've tried something like this both with `Storyboard Name` set and not set inside `Application Scene Manifest` but can't seem to get anything to work. Any Ideas?

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = scene as? UIWindowScene else {return}

    let storyboard: UIStoryboard
    let initViewController: UIViewController

    if (User.sharedInstance.isLoggedIn()) {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        initViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabs") as UIViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initViewController
    } else {
        storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        initViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginLanding") as UIViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initViewController
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the problem is I wasn't setting the window with the scene.

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    guard let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene else {return}
    window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)

    // if user is not logged in then don't use Main storyboard
    if (!User.sharedInstance.isLoggedIn()) {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Login", bundle: nil)
        window?.rootViewController =  storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginLanding")
    }
}
```